# Popup is disabled when clicking gridview paging property in Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

This is My Design Page

```
<a href="#" class="topopup">Click Here Trigger</a>
    <div id="toPopup">
        <div class="close"></div>
        <span class="ecs_tooltip">Press Esc to close <span class="arrow"></span></span>
        <div id="popup_content">
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true"
                AllowPaging="true" PageSize="3" 
                OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging">
            </asp:GridView>             
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <div id="backgroundPopup"></div>
```

This is my Jquery Code

```
jQuery(function($) {
        $("a.topopup").click(function() {
                    setTimeout(function(){ 
                        loadPopup(); 
                    }, 500); 
            return false;
            });
        $("div.close").hover(
                        function() {
                                $('span.ecs_tooltip').show();
                            },
                            function () {
                            $('span.ecs_tooltip').hide();
                            }
               );        
    $(this).keyup(function(event) {
            if (event.which == 27) { 
                disablePopup();  
            }
        });
$("div#backgroundPopup").click(function() {
                disablePopup(); 
            });
        function loading() {
            $("div.loader").show();
    }
    function closeloading() {
            $("div.loader").fadeOut('normal');
        }
    var popupStatus = 0;     
        function loadPopup() {
            if(popupStatus == 0) { 
                    closeloading(); 
                    $("#toPopup").fadeIn(0500);
                        $("#backgroundPopup").css("opacity", "0.7");
                        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn(0001);
                        popupStatus = 1; 
                    }
            }
        function disablePopup() {
                if(popupStatus == 1) { 
                   $("#toPopup").fadeOut("normal");
                    $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("normal");
                    popupStatus = 0; 
                    }
            }
    });
```

Actually when am clicking href link for first time  gridview is popup and when am clicking the paging property of a gridivew the popup is disabled and once again am clicking the href link, the gridview is popup and showing data.

The popup is disabled when am clicking gridview paging property. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do that. Because once you click on the link inside pop-up and then the page will be refreshed and your pop will close.

You need to call all the method using jQuery for `paging` and `sorting`.

Comment: How to call all the method using jquery, can you give example

Comment: You can use jQgrid or jquery datatable for this purpose. http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html